# how do you ban things from subsets

Tags: combinatorics

How can you get the total number of subsets, if you generate all subsets from the set $\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$ but BAN all subsets that either include $A$ and $B$, $B$ and $C$, or $C$ and $D$.

Is there a way to do this non-manually?

I would also appreciate links and general information about the topic!

Comment: Inclusion-Exclusion is great for counting unions (in this case, the set of banned subsets is a union).  Does that count as "manually"?

Comment: dunno what you're talking about

Comment: [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Principle_of_Inclusion-Exclusion) is an introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.

Comment: yes this looks a lot like what i'm asking about, eliminating overcounting. though to be honest I don't understand a lick of the page you sent me. I only just figured out what a set was 20 minutes ago

Answer (score 3):

There are $2^6$ total subsets.  Now let us subtract the banned ones-there are $2^4$ subsets containing $A$ and $B$ and also $2^4$ with each other pair.  We have subtracted the $2^3$ that have $A,B,C$ twice and the $2^3$ that have $B,C,D$ twice, so we have to add them back in once.  Finally the $2^2$ that have $A,B,C,D$ have been counted, subtracted three times, and added twice, so no more correction is necessary.  The final answer is 
$$2^6-3\cdot 2^4+2\cdot 2^3=32$$
This is an example of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Answer (score 2):

I'll show a slightly different approach.  First, let's count the subsets that include $B$ (but don't include $A$ or $C$).  There are $8$ of those.

Now let's count the subsets that include $C$ but don't include $B$ or $D$.  There are $8$ of those.

Finally, let's count the subsets that don't include either $B$ or $C$.  There are $16$ of those.

So there are a total of $32$ subsets that satisfy our conditions.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned, *inclusion-exclusion* is useful here.

We are seeking the number of subsets that either include $A$ and $B$ or $B$ and $C$, or $C$ and $D$. By inclusion-exclusion, this is equal to the number of subsets that contain $A$ and $B$, plus the number that contain $B$ and $C$, plus the number that contain $C$ and $D$, minus the number that contain any combination of these two.

Since the number of subsets of an $n$-element set is $2^n$, this is equal to $2^4 \times 3 - 2^3 \times 2 = 32$.

So the number of subsets we are seeking is $2^6 - 32 = 32$ subsets.

Comment: OP wants to exclude the ones you are counting.  I think the middle term should just be $2$ times because there are just two triplets of interest and the last should not be included because you counted it three times in the first batch and subtracted it twice in the second, so you have it once like you want

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you—I think you’re right.

Answer (score -1):

To "ban" $A$ and $B$, take all the subsets of:
$$
\{C,D,E,F\}.
$$
In more detail, first carry out the calculation
$$
\{A,B,C,D,E,F\} \setminus \{A, B\},
$$
which results in the set $\{C,D,E,F\}$.  Take all subsets of this set.

Comment: I think OP wanted to allow $A$ or $B$ but not both

Comment: @RossMillikan, if they did, it's a straightforward *mutatis mutandis*.  But it doesn't sound to me like they did, not with the "and-or" constructs in the question.

Comment: Yeah what Ross said. Exactly what Ross said.

Comment: No, it is not the same because $\{A,C,E\}$ is an acceptable subset but $\{A,B,E\}$ is not

Comment: I didn't say it was the same.  "Mutatis mutandis" means "making necessary alterations".